# What are the most appropriate PKI based cryptographic protocols for peer to peer communicaton?

Tags: encryption, public-key, pki

I've been trying to find out which is the most appropriate PKI based cryptographic protocol for peer to peer communication. I do understand that they vary with respect to the peer to peer architecture model. It would be wonderful if someone is able to name a few and also the reason behind it.

Comment: What do you mean PKI protocol for P2P???What is the special property of P2P that PKI would do  sth different than issuing certificates and public keys?

Comment: @curious The basic idea of a peer to peer communication being to eliminate the 3rd party where two 2 peers can directly communicate.  Being able to validate a peer without the help of a 3rd party such as the certifying authority and other parameters of the cryptographic protocol which affect the communication such as security, speed , cost etc. Hence which protocol will be the most appropriate for such kind of a model.

Comment: PKI is a trusted third party which certifies  public keys

Comment: @curious No. PKI is a Public Key *Infrastructure*. It includes the entire ecosystem. It's not just a Certificate Authority (CA).

Comment: http://maidsafe.net/Whitepapers/pdf/PeerToPeerPublicKeyInfrastructure.pdf     the following paper refers to a way in which 2 peers can validate themselves without a 3rd party. PKI doesn't necessarily require a trusted 3rd party for working. When I say a peer to peer network here I'm assuming there are no trusted peers on the network. Hence how can I've a PKI based cryptographic protocol for such kind of a network architecture? @curious

Comment: What sort of a protocol are you looking for? PGP [web of trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust) is an example of P2P PKI.

Comment: @otus I would like to know a few PKI based cryptosystems which can be used for p2p communication. So that I could read about it and come to a conclusion by myself regarding which is better.

Comment: Do you mean P2P where two acquantances could communicate by phones and thus be sure from their voices that the right persons are online? I wonder whether even this could be guaranteed to be 100% secure.